# In game stuttering (not FPS)

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, performance

I just recently got a GTX 1050ti to replace my GTX 770. With most games, I can increase the graphics from what they were set at when using my 770.

There is one game, however, where I get stuttering while playing (randomly happens). The FPS stays at 60 (reported by steam and MSI Afterburner) and the temps/usage stay nominal (Afterburner). CPU usage floats around 60%, RAM usage around 4GB.

The stuttering is like a frame drop from 60-20 (even though it doesn't), making it feel like a lower frame rate.

This stuttering only happens in this one game (Rocket League). I had assumed it may be down to my oldish CPU (specs below) and the GFX card sending it data faster than it can process it, but the usage never goes too high.

This issue never happened with my 770 and doesn't happen with any other game using my 1050 (even more demanding ones). I have turned all graphics settings to the bare minimum yet the issue still happens, so it isn't tied to rendering.

The issue may be game specific (optimisation?) but thought I would ask in case any one knows of the specific issue.

```
CPU: i5 4670k @ 3.4ghz
GFX: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
PSU: 750w Corsair
Ram: 8GB DDR3
Windows 10 x86
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rocket League is a fairly well-known and well-optimised game, **however** people seem to be having [similar problems](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/5qwq4z/for_those_who_have_micro_stuttering_issues_with/).

I've got an i7-4790K (similar to yours) and I *highly* doubt that there's any reason for concern there.

I suggest reading the above linked Reddit page, perhaps tweaking your games settings, but also definitely **updating your graphics card driver**, and GeForce Experience (also look at what settings they recommend for your GPU).

There's also a [Steam Community thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/252950/discussions/0/412446890555023295/) that's a bit old but may help you.

Comment: I read through the reddit post and changed the cfg file. Played 2 games and no stuttering. Thank you sir. I did try finding this issue on google but perhaps my search terms were too broad.

Comment: I'm glad I helped!